# clean example of directions with google maps in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

Try to get a working jquery mobile maps direction page. 
There is this example listed:

```
http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#directions_map
```

But the example code is messy and haven't been able to get it working :(. 
Ikea uses it.

```
http://m.ikea.com/nl/nl/stores/415/map/
```

but they also very customized the js so its very hard to see what happens.

Does anyone know of a good clean example or implementation that's easy to follow?

Comment: My suggestion would be to contact the original developer(s) as it's using the jQM alpha version of 1.0 https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/source/browse/tags/2.0.2/demos/jquery-mobile-example-3.html

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Below you can find a basic example of using the Google Maps directions service in a jQuery Mobile page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps geo directions example</title>
        <meta content="en" http-equiv="content-language">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("pageinit", "#map_page", function() {
                initialize();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                calculateRoute();
            });

            var directionDisplay,
                directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
                map;

            function initialize() 
            {
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3426606750, 18.0736160278);

                var myOptions = {
                    zoom:10,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: mapCenter
                }

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));  
            }

            function calculateRoute() 
            {
                var selectedMode = $("#mode").val(),
                    start = $("#from").val(),
                    end = $("#to").val();

                if(start == '' || end == '')
                {
                    // cannot calculate route
                    $("#results").hide();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    var request = {
                        origin:start, 
                        destination:end,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[selectedMode]
                    };

                    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 
                            $("#results").show();
                            /*
                                var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                                for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                                    alert(myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
                                }
                            */
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#results").hide();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="map_page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a href="#">jQuery mobile - Google maps directions service</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:300px;"></div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="from">From</label> 
                        <input type="text" id="from" value="Goteborg, Sweden"/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="to">To</label> 
                        <input type="text" id="to" value="Stockholm, Sweden"/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="mode" class="select">Transportation method:</label>
                        <select name="select-choice-0" id="mode">
                            <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
                            <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
                            <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <a data-icon="search" data-role="button" href="#" id="submit">Get directions</a>
                </div>
                <div id="results" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="directions"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

The below example uses the current position which is automatically located and a target destination address which is given from the user.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var map,
                currentPosition,
                directionsDisplay, 
                directionsService;

            function initialize(lat, lon)
            {
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
                directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

                currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 15,
                   center: currentPosition,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });

                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                 var currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: currentPosition,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Current position"
                });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                google.maps.event.addListener(currentPositionMarker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent("Current position: latitude: " + lat +" longitude: " + lon);
                    infowindow.open(map, currentPositionMarker);
                });
            }

            function locError(error) {
                // initialize map with a static predefined latitude, longitude
               initialize(59.3426606750, 18.0736160278);
            }

            function locSuccess(position) {
                initialize(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            }

            function calculateRoute() {
                var targetDestination = $("#target-dest").val();
                if (currentPosition && currentPosition != '' && targetDestination && targetDestination != '') {
                    var request = {
                        origin:currentPosition, 
                        destination:targetDestination,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode["DRIVING"]
                    };

                    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 

                            /*
                                var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                                for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                                    alert(myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
                                }
                            */
                            $("#results").show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#results").hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#results").hide();
                }
            }

            $(document).live("pagebeforeshow", "#map_page", function() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locSuccess, locError);
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#directions-button', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                calculateRoute();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="target-dest">Target Destination:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="target-dest" id="target-dest" value=""  />
                </div>
                <a href="#" id="directions-button" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Get Directions</a>
                <div id="results" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="directions"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The below example locates the current position and it automatically calculates the distance and displays the route details between the current location and a static predefined destination location.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var map,
                currentPosition,
                directionsDisplay, 
                directionsService,
                destinationLatitude = 59.3426606750,
                destinationLongitude = 18.0736160278;

            function initializeMapAndCalculateRoute(lat, lon)
            {
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
                directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

                currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 15,
                   center: currentPosition,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });

                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                 var currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: currentPosition,
                    map: map,
                    title: "Current position"
                });

                // current position marker info
                /*
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                google.maps.event.addListener(currentPositionMarker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent("Current position: latitude: " + lat +" longitude: " + lon);
                    infowindow.open(map, currentPositionMarker);
                });
                */

                // calculate Route
                calculateRoute();
            }

            function locError(error) {
               // the current position could not be located
            }

            function locSuccess(position) {
                // initialize map with current position and calculate the route
                initializeMapAndCalculateRoute(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            }

            function calculateRoute() {

                var targetDestination =  new google.maps.LatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude);
                if (currentPosition != '' && targetDestination != '') {

                    var request = {
                        origin: currentPosition, 
                        destination: targetDestination,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode["DRIVING"]
                    };

                    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); 

                            /*
                                var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                                for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {
                                    alert(myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
                                }
                            */
                            $("#results").show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#results").hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#results").hide();
                }
            }

            $(document).live("pagebeforeshow", "#map_page", function() {
                // find current position and on success initialize map and calculate the route
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locSuccess, locError);
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="results" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="directions"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is a cleaner example than the ones provided on the site thx. But the problem is this still has no directions **based on the current location (gps on iphone for example ) so I cannot flag it as the correct answer. I try to build upon your example and add the geo stuff

Comment: Would you check my updated answer. I added an example which uses the current location.

Comment: thanks so much, really messed around with this but google maps can be tricky to get working. Only 1 last problem i have, I would like to have directions calculated *after* user gives his location. Would you know how to do that too? I removed the directions input field and button and set the value of destination hardcoded in the js. Final step would be to have it calc the directions after the user gives his current location

Comment: @Rubytastic You're welcome :) You want to have a static destination location and the map should calculate the distance and the route details between the current position and the static destination location, right? I have updated my answer with a corresponding example.

Comment: Many thanks I see I was close but missing the essential knowledge of the jquery map plugins and jquery. Perhaps one LAST question I may ask you. It seems that safari in iphone sometimes not pickup the user location. Do you use this code yourself and noticed it or is the code not 100% proof? I read lots of reports that iphone and safari not always pickup location ( and user have to reload page again to get the geo location access popup appear )

Comment: Hi, the sample examples are based on the proposed W3C Geolocation API Specification (http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). Regarding the Safari in iPhone, Apple states that geographic locations are available in iOS3.0 and later. (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/GettingGeographicalLocations/GettingGeographicalLocations.html).

Comment: Noticed there are *no* maps displayed if you do not share your location, would that be something to could be fixed for the sake of completeness? Do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: @Rubytastic Sorry, I haven't found a solution yet for the case you are mentioning.