# android.permission.INTERNET on mobile site (not app)

Tags: android, mobile, location

I want to show the user geo location on Android:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

It doesn't work on Android, I read on the web that I need to allow permissions in the file AndroidMainfest.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.sample.someapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

But this is related only for an Android app, not a mobile site. What should I do?
I tried adding the file like that:

```
<xml id="equipdet"  src="AndroidMainfest.xml" async="false"></xml>
```

It's not working

Answer (score 0):

Permissions in AndroidManifest are for Android apps, they are not related to mobile sites a user is visiting with a browser.  Take a look at this detailed answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885172/1224600

Comment: i see no solution there. my code is working fine on regular pc browsers (IE, chrome, firefox). but not on android browser. any suggestions ?

Comment: Try modifying Android Location settings (Settings->Location access) and Chrome Location settings (Chrome->Settings->Content Settings->Google location settings)

Comment: i have found my solution with google map jquery mobile. see here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345479/clean-example-of-directions-with-google-maps-in-jquery-mobile