# Geolocation possible, but inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to help detect different things on a browser. Now, I know most recent browsers support geolocation ([caniuse chart here](http://caniuse.com/geolocation)), but what if it is turned off by the user preferences? In that case, Modernizr returns true with the `geolocation` class on the `html` tag since it does have support.

I've been using geolocation support to make a "get directions" type of map. Here's the gist of it:

### What works

- The map works fine with directions to the desired destination;
- In browsers with no support at all, a map highlighting the desired destination's address (say a restaurant) is shown; *This has been kept in as a fallback to prevent having an empty space on the page.*

### Where I'am stuck

I've been looking around and can't seem to find any documentation on how to deal with a browser (mobile or not) which does *support* geolocation but has it **disabled** by user preferences.

### What I've been working with

#### CSS

I'm working off of this [here post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13481594/2748327) which shows a working solution where the user is shown a map with directions to the proper destination if geolocation is supported. In the case where geolocation is *not* supported, I have an alternate content div ready to show.

```
/* geo location is supported */
html.geolocation #regular-map {
    display: block;
}
html.geolocation #alternate-map {
    display: none;
}
/* geo location is NOT supported, show alternate map */
html.no-geolocation #regular-map {
    display: none;
}
html.no-geolocation #alternate-map {
    display: block;
}
```

### What I've tried

#### Permission denied error code

I've tried using this type of detection to see if the user has blocked geolocation (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092450/2748327)), but when I test it on a browser where I did block it, I get the notification of "supported":

```
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
    alert("supported");
}
else
{
    function errorCallback(error)
    {
        if (error.code = error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        {
            alert("blocked");
        }   
        else
        {
            alert("not supported");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Bottom Line

Bottom line, what I need is to see if the browser supports geolocation, but the user has chosen to Deny using geolocation services.

---

## Edit

The general idea is like this. I'm more comfortable with PHP, so here's the idea:

```
<?php
    if($hasgeosupport)
    {
?>
        <script src="hassupport.js"></script>
        <div id="geolocation"></div>
<?php
    }
    else
    if($hasgeosupport)
    {
?>
        <script src="fallback.js"></script>
        <div id="fallback"></div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

## Edit 2

Here's where I'm at, this morning. I have the code creating the proper HTML structure. However, the map is not loading.

```
if (navigator.geolocation)
{
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // Does not create HTML without the above line
        $.getScript('js/maps.js'); // includes required scripts and variables needed
        var regular_map = '<div data-role="content"><div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;"><div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div></div><div id="results" style="display:none;"><div id="directions"></div></div></div>';
        $("#basic-map").prepend(regular_map);
    }
}
else
{
    // fallback here
}
```

I don't know why this is not working for me. I have the proper scripts, the HTML is generated.

Same goes for the fallback. My HTML is generated, yet the maps never show.

Answer (score 2):

This has always worked for me

```
if(navigator.geolocation) { // it's supported

    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
         console.log('Geolocation is enabled, and the user approved');
    }, function (error) { 
         if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
             console.log('The user declined');
         }else{
             console.log('Either turned of, or another error occurred ?');
         }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

based on the edited question, you can load those scripts and insert the elements dynamically based on the result from the geolocation:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) { // it's supported
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
        $('body').append( $('<div />', {id : 'geolocation'}) );
        $.getScript('hassupport.js', function() {
            // script loaded
        });
    }, function (error) { 
         if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
             console.log('The user declined');
         }else{
             console.log('Either turned of, or another error occurred ?');
         }
        //either way
        $('body').append( $('<div />', {id : 'fallback'}) );
        $.getScript('fallback.js', function() {
            // script loaded
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I've added an edit to show pretty much what I want to do as it would be done in PHP. Your code does exactly what I need, but I would need to get a JS condition (or variable) into PHP, but I can only see AJAX doing this, and I believe this would slow down the process quite a lot.

Comment: @PubliDesign - added an edit! You can just load the scripts and change the markup based on wether or not the geolocation was successful.

Comment: I've changed your sample code to have `getScript` inside a `when` since I'm loading multiple script files (original code is 'as is'). However, when I get to the .done part, I can't get anything to work normally. Normally, I would go `<div id="regular">...</div>` and `<script>var abc; ...</script>`, but inside the `.done` (after the `.when`) I can't get it to work, not even after using the `.append` function. Once I use my vars, the code seems to die. I tried using a function, but that didn't seem to work either...

Comment: To help you understand where I'm going, I created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky85y/). Notice I added two commented alerts. The first one works fine; when the scripts are loaded, I get the alert saying "inside done". However, the map never shows, and I don't get the second alert saying "end of done". *Sigh.*

Comment: I've added another edit for sample code, including a document.ready

Answer (score 0):

I've found a working solution.

### Notes

- I still want to show directions (E.g. Turn left on Road 4, etc.).

### Code

#### HTML

```
<div id="basic-map" class="mymap" data-role="page">
    <div id="regularmap" data-role="content"></div>

    <div id="fallback">
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 350px"></div>
        <div class="infobox-wrapper">
            <div id="infobox">
                <h3>My Business</h3>
                <p>
                    123, Fake Street <br />
                    City (Province) A1B 2C3 <br /> <br />
                    <a href="tel:+15555551234">555 555-1234</a>
                </p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/* Regular ------------------------------------- */
html.geolocation #basic-map {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
html.geolocation #basic-map #regularmap {
    height: 350px;
}
html.geolocation #basic-map #fallback {
    display: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
/* Fallback ------------------------------------ */
html.no-geolocation #regularmap {
    display: none;
}
    html.no-geolocation #basic-map {
        position: relative;
    }
    html.no-geolocation #infobox {
        border:2px solid black;
        margin-top:8px;
        background:#333;
        color:#FFF;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        padding:10px;
        padding:1rem;
        -webkit-border-radius:4px;
        -moz-border-radius:4px;
        border-radius:4px;
        text-shadow:0 -1px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 8px #000;
        box-shadow:0 0 8px #000;
        line-height:120%;
        position:absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 32px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    html.no-geolocation #infobox:after {
        content: "";
        width: 147px;
        height: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -9px;
        right: 35px;
        background: url(../img/tipbox.gif) top right no-repeat;
    }
    html.no-geolocation #infobox a {
        color:#fff !important;
        font-size:14px
    }
    html.no-geolocation #infobox a:hover {
        color:#e2e2e2 !important
    }
    html.no-geolocation #infobox h3 {
        color:#fff !important;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-top:0
    }
    html.no-geolocation #infobox #infoBox img {
        position:absolute;
        top:15px;
        right:5px;
        z-index:5
    }
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
    {  
        var gps = (position.coords.latitude+position.coords.longitude);  
        window.GlobalVar = gps;

        window.myLatt = position.coords.latitude;
        window.myLong = position.coords.longitude;

        initialize();
    });

    var Center=new google.maps.LatLng(46.327256,-72.560813);
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize()
    {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var properties =
        {
            center:Center,
            zoom:16,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("regularmap"), properties);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var marker=new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position:Center
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
        Route();
    }

    function Route()
    {
        startLat  =     window.myLatt;
        startLong =  window.myLong;

        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLong);
        var end =new google.maps.LatLng(46.327254,-72.560813);
        var request =
        {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status)
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
} // if(navigator.geolocation)
else
{
    $.getScript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true');
    $.getScript('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js');
    function initialize()
    {
        /* ----- Variables ---------------------------------- */
        var myLat = 46.327269;
        var myLong = -72.560779;
        var iconURL = 'img/logo-map-marker-large.png';
        var myClose = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif";
        var bbl_bg = "url('img/tipbox.gif') no-repeat";
        /* ----- Scripted ----------------------------------- */
        var loc,map,marker,infobox;loc=new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLong);map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{zoom:15,center:loc,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:map,position:loc,icon:iconURL,visible:true});infobox=new InfoBox({content:document.getElementById("infobox"),disableAutoPan:false,maxWidth:150,pixelOffset:new google.maps.Size(-140,0),zIndex:null,boxStyle:{background:bbl_bg,opacity:0.75,width:"320px"},closeBoxMargin:"2px 2px 2px 2px",closeBoxURL:myClose,infoBoxClearance:new google.maps.Size(1,1)});google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(){infobox.open(map,this);map.panTo(loc)});
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
} // else
}); // $(document).ready(function()
</script>
```

#### images

toolbox.gif

[image: Tipbox]

logo-map-marker-large.png (smaller version also created, not used in this example, though)

[image: "We Are Here" icon]